# WPF Frame Uri does not work when calling as project reference

Tags: wpf, url, uri, frame, relative-path

I have a simple frame in my WPF project in VS2010. The Uri is called in codebehind with:

```
Dim U As New Uri("Pages/PageTranslate.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
```

Now I am using this project as reference in another project. I am calling the FrameProject by using a instance like

```
New FrameProjectInstance1
```

Now I receive an error:

> System.IO.IOException was unhandled
>     Message=Cannot locate resource 'pages/pagetranslate.xaml'.
>     Source=PresentationFramework
>     StackTrace:
>          at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>          at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
>          at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
>          at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
>          at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()

```
   ...
```

I've tried: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Y5978 without luck. Always got the same error. Also with:

```
        U = New Uri("/Pages/PageTranslate.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        U = New Uri("pack://application:,,,Pages/PageTranslate.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        U = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/Pages/PageTranslate.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out this is working for me. Hope it helps other too:

```
  'In Application.Xaml
  Public Shared NavigationService As NavigationService 'set when MainWindow.xaml is Loaded 

  Public Shared Function NavigationUri(ByVal Path As String) As Uri
    Dim asm As System.Reflection.Assembly
    asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly

    Dim U As Uri
    U = New Uri("pack://application:,,,/" & asm.GetName().Name & ";component/" & Path, UriKind.Absolute)
    Return U
End Function
```

Calling that way:

```
Application.NavigationService.Source = Application.NavigationUri("Pages/PageAutoTranslation.xaml")
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use this: "MyDll;/Pages/PageTranslate.xaml"? Where MyDll is dll's name of your FrameProject.

Comment: thanks Iverzin. Your idea was good. Just syntax and the how to did not work exact that way. I found a solution and post it. Thanks.